# mySQL client takes incorrect hostname

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-connector

I have created a mysql database using AWS RDS. However, when I try to access it using `mysql` client like below, it seems to try to resolve the hostname to some incorrect name and the connection fails. What am I missing?

```
$ mysql -u admin -h iraas.XXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P3306 -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'c-99-526-987-78.hsd7.wa.comcast.net' (using password: YES)
```

(Notice that it is trying to connect to some *.comcast.net host rather than the one provided in the command line parameter)

Comment: please read the manual https://docs.aws.amazon.com//latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html and follow the steps

Comment: url to manual is invalid now